# IEWebDriver Error: Driver does not support manipulating HTML5 web storage. Use the HasWebStorage property to test for the driver capability

Tags: javascript, c#, html, selenium-webdriver

I use Specflow, Selenium and c# to automate the UI.

I try to get performance values from Selenium.WebDriver.IEDriver 3.8.0.
After I open the "url" of any website I run this script:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jsExec = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driverInterface;

var res = jsExec.ExecuteScript(@"var timings = window.performance.timing || {}; return timings;");
```

This code work perfectly for Chrome. But for IE webDriver I have error.
If I open DEV tool(F12) of the IE browser and run this code in console it works perfectly.

The most meaningful error message that I found in "res" object is:

"Driver does not support manipulating HTML5 web storage. Use the HasWebStorage property to test for the driver capability"

And I don't know what to do?

Comment: did you run the  `haswebstorage ` property ?

Comment: I really don't know what this mean: to run the haswebstorage property. "driverInterface.haswebstorage" is not possible. The driver don't have this...

Comment: console out the jsExec.HasWebStorage  Property to see if it supports the storage of the conten,t

Comment: Again jsExec.HasWebStorage is not possible. The options are: Equals, ExecuteScript, ExecuteAnyScript, GetHashCode, GetType, ToString

Comment: Is there any chance that your SpecFlow script is attempting to call `driver.WebStorage` somewhere?